# How to write a dictionary value when calling a function in Power Query/M Language?

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery

I have a function that queries data from an external api (making a power connector). I need one of my inputs for the api to be json text (could be nested json). However from the Power BI UI side, I can only pass in things like numbers, text, lists... I could write it as a JSON encoded string like this

```
MyLibrary.GetData("{""key"":{""key2"":""value""}}")
```

But this looks messy. I would like to write it natively like this for example (then convert it to json text in M language).

```
MyLibrary.GetData({"key":{"key2":"value"}})
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. There is a `record` type like this `[key=Value]`. Value can be any type.